# Python - Search and add file with similar pattern into groups using module re

Tags: python, regex

I have a folder contains of files `["usc_hhx1", "usc_hhx2", "usc_hhh1", "usc_hhz1", "usc_hhz2]`

How do I write a program to match each pattern `("hhx", "hhh", "hhz")` into their groups?

This is how I get my files and I need to sort them out. Please help, thank you!

```
import os
import re

usc1 = []
for file in os.listdir("ginsburgdata/USC1/USC1"):
    ############### SORT FILES OUT BASED ON THEIR NAMES HERE ###############
    #### hz_key = re.compile("HHZ")

    usc1.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "ginsburgdata", "usc1", file))
```

I have tried doing some research but I'm stuck at execution

Comment: What is the desired output of your desired program?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to group files into separate groups by a pattern:

```py
import re

files = ["usc_hhx1", "usc_hhx2", "usc_hhh1", "usc_hhz1", "usc_hhz2"]

pat = re.compile(r"hh[xzh]")

groups = {}
for f in files:
    match = pat.search(f)
    if match:
        groups.setdefault(match.group(0), []).append(f)

print(groups)
```

Prints:

```py
{
  'hhx': ['usc_hhx1', 'usc_hhx2'], 
  'hhh': ['usc_hhh1'], 
  'hhz': ['usc_hhz1', 'usc_hhz2']
}
```